# JSON parsing and displaying in different tables using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS here.
can any one please help me how to parse and display the Json Data in different tables using Angular JS

`[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "isActive": false,
        "balance": 1025.00,
        "picture": "http://www.placekitten.com/50/50",
        "age": 25,
        "name": "Daisy Mcneil",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Verbus",
        "email": "daisymcneil@verbus.com",
        "phone": "+1 (936) 586-3983",
        "address": "849 Newkirk Placez, Laurelton, Nevada, 1086",
        "registered": "2012-07-15T13:46:25 +07:00",
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Debra Blair"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Henry Avila"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Jody Stark"
            }
        ],
        "service": "cherry"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "isActive": true,
        "balance": -2884.00,
        "picture": "http://www.placekitten.com/50/50",
        "age": 23,
        "name": "Schroeder Atkinson",
        "gender": "male",
        "company": "Twiggery",
        "email": "schroederatkinson@twiggery.com",
        "phone": "+1 (861) 449-2254",
        "address": "259 Highland Avenue, Riner, Vermont, 905",
        "registered": "1998-01-17T08:16:34 +08:00",
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Mendoza Figueroa"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Lenore Morales"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Winifred Bowen"
            }
        ],
        "service": "lemon"
    }
]`

I want to display each JSON object in the different table with a buttion which toggles the table in the html.

the above is the JSON data available...

thanks in advance.

The skeleton for the code is available here https://github.com/50Cubes/WebappTest

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for index.html file -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="ViewJson">

<table>
<th>
<td>id</td>
<td>isActive</td>
<td>balance</td>
<td>picture</td>
<td>age</td>
<td>name</td>  
<td>gender</td>
<td>company</td>        
<td>email</td>      
<td>phone</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>registered</td>       
<td>service</td></th>
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts">                      
<td>{{post.id}}</td>     
<td>{{post.isActive}}</td>      
<td>{{post.balance}}</td>       
<td>{{post.picture}}</td>       
<td>{{post.age}}</td>       
<td>{{post.name}}</td>      
<td>{{post.gender}}</td>        
<td>{{post.company}}</td>       
<td>{{post.email}}</td>     
<td>{{post.phone}}</td>     
<td>{{post.address}}</td>       
<td>{{post.registered}}</td>        
<td>{{post.service}}</td></tr></table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for main.js file. Here I am assuming that the name of json file is posts.js -

```
var app=angular.module('MyApp',[]);
function ViewJson($scope, $http)
{$http({method: 'POST', url: 'js/posts.json'}).success(function(data)
    {$scope.posts = data;});
}
```